# Live Activity Flutter with iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, swiftui, widgetliveactivity

How to fix this status
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(LIVE_ACTIVITY_ERROR, can't launch live activity, The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.ActivityKit.ActivityInput error 0.), null)

When I'm trying run application Live Activity, and then it is showing message like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible fix is to be sure to add this property in the `Info.plist` file. Be sure to add it in the `Runner` & `Widget Extension` file.

```
<key>NSSupportsLiveActivities</key>
<true/>
```